# Multiple Scatter plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

i wanna make multiple scatter plot using matplotlib how can I subplots the scatter what I mean is to make len(features) plot scatter, I've tried this but didn't succeed

```
for each in featureset:
      i=0
      fig,ax=plt.subplot(len(features))
      ax[i].scatter(df[each],df[Target],color='Blue')
      i+=1
```

so i solved my problem from myself here the solution

```
 import seaborn as sns
 features=df.columns[:len(df.columns)-1]
 target=df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]
 sns.pairplot(df,x_vars=features,y_vars=target)
```

that's it, a very easy solution

Comment: Please start by having a look at how for-statements actually look like in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Make sure your code is formatted correctly. Explain what you mean by "didn't work".

Comment: I solved my problem from myself i used seaborn library